# What happens when pointers are typecasted?

Tags: c

During some trial and error, came across this. It is outputting 513 as the value, cant figure out why.

```
int a;
char *x;
x =(char *) &a;
a = 512;
x[0]=1;
x[1]=2;
printf("%d\n ",a);
```

Comment: `(2<<8)+1` equals 513 on a little endian machine

Answer (score 1):

On a typical x86 platform an `int` is four bytes wide and is stored little endian. Little endian means the bytes are stored in reverse, least significant to most significant. The number 512 is represented in memory as 2 × 2<sup>8</sup>, or:

```
{ 0x00, 0x02, 0x00, 0x00 }
// LSB              MSB
// 2^0  2^8   2^16  2^24
```

After the two assignments you have:

```
{ 0x01, 0x02, 0x00, 0x00 }
// LSB              MSB
// 2^0  2^8   2^16  2^24
```

Converting these four bytes back to decimal you have 1 × 2<sup>0</sup> + 2 × 2<sup>8</sup> = 1 + 512 = 513.

Comment: it also works if integers are 8 or 16 or whatever size, since it's little endian